# Postman to define variables list once at the begining of collection

Tags: postman

I need to define set of variables and they shuldn't be mixed with environment variables. At the begining of collection set I define them

```
pm.globals.set('a', 1);
```

and clear it athe the end ot tests set

```
pm.globals.clear();
```

It works if I have consecutive set of tests. I need something like postman "collection pre-request script", but it is executed before every test. How to set some variables once before collection or folder execution?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to set variables at the collection level then you can define those through the collection settings:
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables/#defining-collection-variables

If you want to run the same pre-request script for every request in a collection (or folder), that can be done from the collection/folder settings too:
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/pre_request_scripts/#adding-a-pre-request-script-to-a-collection-or-folder

Comment: Thank you. I know it. I need to set a pre-request script that would be executed once before my collection or folder tests set would be executed. Collection variables are read -only, I need something editable.

Comment: Actually, I think what he is asking is how to get that pre-request script to run ONE time before the entire collection runs.  What I am trying to do is to have a script that runs once, sets the value of a global variable - and then for each subsequent "test" in the collection it can use that global variable.  Using the approach you linked to, it will run that script before each and every single "test" in the collection.

Comment: You can add a setup folder/request to the top of your collection - or - you can add as a collection/folder level script and write a condition which will cause the script to only run once (e.g. store a global `hasRun` variable which you check before execution and toggle once the script has run once)